# Add extra class to a pre-trained softmax classifier

Tags: classification, neural-networks

## Question

I'm wondering if some could add an extra class to a pre-trained softmax-ed neural network, trained for multi-class classification problem, without reusing the old training data.

## Details

Let's say you have a 3-layer NN, with an output matrix's image living in a 10 dimensional space. The whole is softmax-ed, for outputting my CPD, and trained by backprop.

Now I'd like to add and train for a couple more classes, going from 10 to 12. I have training data for the new two classes but I would avoid resuming the training data for the classes that have been already trained.

Is this possible? I don't think so.. But I'm here for an extra opinion.